# Xamarin form displaying temperature value

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

I want to display 36.53°C value inside xamarin form.

How Can I Display it Using grid and label?
36.65 will have large font size and it unit °C will have small font size.
Again °C will displayed at bottom corner of number.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`FormattedText`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.Label.FormattedText/) in `Label`:

```
<Label>
    <Label.FormattedText>
        <FormattedString>
            <Span Text="36.65" FontSize="Large" />
            <Span Text="&#186;C" FontSize="Small" />
        </FormattedString>
    </Label.FormattedText>
</Label>
```

[image: ios-screenshot] .  [image: android-screenshot]